# Import PyMySql error : No module named 'PyMySql', under windows 10 / Spyder (Anaconda3) / Python 3.8 /MySQL 5.7

Tags: pymysql

I just check many posts about this error code and try to install/uninstall pymysql , followed from the suggestion of https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

However, I got two different result in Spyder and cmd window

`import pymysql`

Spyder ->  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL'

cmd window -> Normal without warning

I found a post talking about pymysql was not supporting with Python 3.8, but no any official article mention about it

https://ithelp.ithome.com.tw/questions/10198846

Does anyone have solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue ,i resolved it by uninstalling and reinstalling the pymysql

once try it may work

uninstalling:
"pip uninstall pymysql"

installing:
"python3 -m pip install PyMySQL"

if it still now works then try force install
"pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall pymysql"

it may works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but it still not works   : (

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I found the error comes from anaconnda version issue and upgraded follower by the article below.

After anoconda upgrade and re-install pymysql, the error was fixed :)

https://www.itread01.com/content/1546672442.html